# Default color scheme for Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, system-installation, colors

This is not so much a question but a request for a change to the defaults.

Though it is quite possible my issue is related to something that I'm doing this issue has been around for many years (and across many different machines, in my case).

With that, why is the default color scheme for Ubuntu server such that the directory color is dark blue on a black background?  This makes reading the name of the folder almost impossible, in my case.

Is there a way I can change the color scheme during the installation process or do I have to modify my .bashrc on each new installation manually?

Comment: The dark blue is quite easy to read on my laptop screen. I guess it depends on your display setup.

Comment: I am slightly color-blind to the blue/green range.  Maybe that is the issue.  That said, shouldn't we account for color-blinded people for our default settings?

Comment: @DaxMickelson If you want to make a suggestion, you can file a bug report on Launchpad, probably against the [coreutils package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils). More info here: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/301745)